# I want to make a Dynamic Routing by picking up the SELECTIVE ELEMENTS FROM ARRAY OF OBJECTS --- TYPESCRIPT

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing, dynamic-routing

**1. all-trades.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-trades',
  templateUrl: './all-trades.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-trades.component.css'],
})
export class AllTradesComponent implements OnInit {

// This is my Array of Object

  crops = [
    {
      name: 'Rice',
      checked: true,
      subCategory: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Basmati',
          isActive: true,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Ammamore',
          isActive: true,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'Wheat',
      checked: true,
      subCategory: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Durum',
          isActive: true,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Emmer',
          isActive: true,
        },
      ],
    }, {
      name: 'Barley',
      checked: true,
      subCategory: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Hulless Barley',
          isActive: true,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Barley Flakes',
          isActive: true,
        },
      ],
    }
  ]



  onChange(event, index, item) {
    item.checked = !item.checked;
    console.log(index, event, item);
  }

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void { }

  
}
```

**2. all-trades.component.html**

```
<app-header></app-header>
<div
  fxLayout="row"
  fxLayout.lt-md="column"
  fxLayoutAlign="space-between start"
  fxLayoutAlign.lt-md="start stretch"
>
  <div class="container-outer" fxFlex="20">
    <div class="filters">
      <section class="example-section">
        <span class="example-list-section">
          <h1>Select Crop</h1>
        </span>
        <span class="example-list-section">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let crop of crops">
              <mat-checkbox
                [checked]="crop.checked"
                (change)="onChange($event, i, crop)"
              >
                {{ crop.name }}
              </mat-checkbox>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </span>
      </section>

      <section class="example-section">
        <span class="example-list-section">
          <h1>Select District</h1>
        </span>
        <span class="example-list-section">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let district of districts">
              <mat-checkbox>
                {{ district.name }}
              </mat-checkbox>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </span>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="content container-outer" fxFlex="80">
    <mat-card
      class="crop-card"
      style="min-width: 17%"
      *ngFor="let crop of crops"
      [hidden]="!crop.checked"
    >
    <!-- I tried the logic here to navigate to sub-Category Array by its id.
    But I failed -->
      <a
        [routerLink]="['/all-trades', crop.id]"
        routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
      >
        <mat-card-header>
          <img
            mat-card-avatar
            class="example-header-image"
            src="/assets/icons/crops/{{ crop.name }}.PNG"
            alt="crop-image"
          />
          <mat-card-title>{{ crop.name }}</mat-card-title>
          <mat-card-subtitle>100 Kgs</mat-card-subtitle>
        </mat-card-header>
      </a>
      <mat-card-content>
        <p>PRICE</p>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
  </div>
</div>

<app-footer></app-footer>
```

[image]

Here You guys can see on my webpage there is couples of cards named as "RICE", "WHEAT", "BARLY"
All just I want to do is by clicking on RICE my code should navigate to another component page and display the name of subCategory name from my Array of Object.
Similarly, it should also work for "WHEAT" and "BARLEY" as well
Example: When I click on Wheat Card it should navigate to different page and display the name of subCategory of Wheat section.

```
crops = [
    {
      name: 'Rice', <---- 1. Go here
      checked: true,
      subCategory: [ <-- 2. Go to subCategory and fetch the name of the "RICE" on different Page
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Basmati',
          isActive: true,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Ammamore',
          isActive: true,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: 'Wheat',
      checked: true,
      subCategory: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Durum',
          isActive: true,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Emmer',
          isActive: true,
        },
      ],
    }, {
      name: 'Barley',
      checked: true,
      subCategory: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: 'Hulless Barley',
          isActive: true,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: 'Barley Flakes',
          isActive: true,
        },
      ],
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [BehaviorSubject](https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0) to do the same

app-routing.component.ts // define route path

```
 const routes: Routes = [
 //other routes
 { path:'crop/:name', component:CropComponent}
 ]
```

crop.ts  //model the interface for crop

```
export class crop{
  name: string;
  checked: boolean;
  subCategory:Subcategory[];
```

}

```
export class Subcategory{
   id: number;
   name: string;
   isActive: boolean;
}
```

service.ts  //create a subject and define getter and setter methods

```
export class CropService {
private selectedCrop= new BehaviorSubject<Crop>(null);

setCrop(crop:Crop){
 this.selectedCrop.next(crop);
 }

getCrop(){
return this.selectedCrop.asObservable().pipe(skipWhile(val=> val === null)); 
}
```

}

all-trades.component.html  //Replace the routerLink with click event

```
<mat-card
  class="crop-card"
  style="min-width: 17%"
  *ngFor="let crop of crops"
  [hidden]="!crop.checked"
>

  <a
   (click)="onSelect(crop)"
    routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
  >
    <mat-card-header>
      <img
        mat-card-avatar
        class="example-header-image"
        src="/assets/icons/crops/{{ crop.name }}.PNG"
        alt="crop-image"
      />
      <mat-card-title>{{ crop.name }}</mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle>100 Kgs</mat-card-subtitle>
    </mat-card-header>
  </a>
  <mat-card-content>
    <p>PRICE</p>
  </mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

all-trades.component.ts //emit the selected crop and route to the same component

```
constructor(private service: Cropservice, private router:Router){}

onSelect(selectedCrop:Crop){
this.service.setCrop(selectedCrop);
this.router.navigateByUrl(`crop/${crop.name}`);
}
```

crop.component.ts // subscribe to the subject and store the crop data locally

```
crop: Crop
export class CropComponent implements OnInit{

ngOnInit(){
this.service.getCrop().subscribe((selectedCrop:Crop)=>this.crop = 
selectedCrop)
}
}
```

crop.component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let category of crop.subCategory">{{category.id}}</div>
```

Comment: Hey Pallavi, I really appreciate your effort.... But its does not work for me ... Do you have some another method. Like parametrized routing or something you can suggest or any doc file which can solve my issue.... Once again Thanks for taking such effort 

Comment: @faisal moinuddin May I know why it isn't working so I can frame answer based on that

Comment: I have done exactly what you have explained but after running my angular project its giving me blank white page, well also I tried my extra masalas but still its not worked....

Comment: I guess something is wrong in crop.component.ts or all-trades.component.ts

Comment: Can you provide a stackblitz link for this app. Issue could be with the routing

Comment: Sure, give me some time !

Comment: Hey Pallavi ! I tried on link my git hub repo with stackblitz but its getting fail, I dont know why !.... Do you have any other way ? may I share you my git hub link.. will that works for you ?

Comment: 1. Go to pages 2. all-trades....... Please solve kr de yaar mera problem    

Comment: Really sorry! I waited for sometime, later caught up with the work. I will look into your code asap. Sorry Again!

Comment: Hey Pallavi, I totally understand its the festival season and please no need to say sorry n all its totally okay .  But can you please try to solve my issue. such mai mera to dimag he kharab ho gaya hai....

Comment: Issue is in your app-routing module. You cannot have empty path for multiple components. https://angular.io/api/router/Route#empty-path check this

Comment: Ofcourse!! https://stackoverflow.com/users/13596406/pallavi This made my day too. Thanks

Comment: Cool ! Once again Thanks 